# Поворот черепашки на +15 градусов каждый цикл, как реализовать?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Здравствуйте. Я новичок в языке C#, прохожу пока курсы от MVA, там задавали ДЗ, я его выполнил, но спустя пару уроков, узнав о новых вещах, решил укоротить код того ДЗ и сделать его лучше(в моем представление). И собственно наткнулся на одну непонятную пока для меня проблему :(

В общем если убрать цикл в методе Main, то моя черепашка рисует линию 75, потом поворачивает на -45 градусов и рисует еще линию 75, после она возвращается в начальную точку. Вот мне надо сделать чтобы следующий ее ход был, рисовать линию 75, поворачивать на **-45 + 15 = -30** (новый ее угол поворота) и рисовать линию 75, возвращаться на исходную точку и так делать 7 раз.

**Вот код:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = -45;
        int len = 150;
        Turtle.Speed = 10;

        for (int i = n; i <= 45; i++)
        {
            Draw(len, n);
        }

    }

    static void Draw(int len, int n)
    {
        int[] array = new int [2];

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            Turtle.Move(len / 2);
            Turtle.Turn(array[i] = n);
        }

        Turtle.Turn(180 - n);

        for (int i = 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            Turtle.Move(len / 2);
            Turtle.Turn(-array[i]);
        }

        Turtle.Turn(-180 + n);
    }
```

*Еще раз заранее прошу, не кидаться тапками. Я совсем новичок в языке C#.*

Comment: Ну, ответ вот на прямо так поставленный вопрос — никак. Но вы задаёте не тот вопрос. Правильный вопрос: а какой _смысл_ этой переменной?

Comment: @VladD Возможно, не отрицаю. Я новичок во всем этом деле еще. Мне надо чтобы во 2ом цикле for переменная j равнялась переменной n + 15. То есть если я поменяю значение Draw (150, **-45**) на другое, то и в цикле for значение у j тоже сменится. Наверное как то так.

Comment: Видимо вы правы, я не правильно задал свой вопрос. В общем если убрать циклы, то моя черепашка рисует линию 50, потом поворачивает на -45 градусов и рисует еще линию 50, после она возвращается в начальную точку. Вот мне надо сделать чтобы следующий ее ход был, рисовать линию 50, поворачивать -45 + новый угол 15 и рисовать линию 50, возвращаться на исходную точку и так делать 7 раз.

Answer (score 3):

Допер сам :) Сделал то что хотел. Спасибо тем кто помог с переменной.

Новый код:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int ang = -60;
        int new_ang = 15;
        int len = 150;
        Turtle.Speed = 10;


        for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
        {
            Draw(len, ang = ang + new_ang);
        }


    }

    static void Draw(int len, int ang)
    {
        int[] array = new int [2];

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            Turtle.Move(len / 2);
            Turtle.Turn(array[i] = ang);
        }

        Turtle.Turn(180 - ang);

        for (int i = 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            Turtle.Move(len / 2);
            Turtle.Turn(-array[i]);
        }

        Turtle.Turn(-180 + ang);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Честно сказать не вижу особого смысла в прокидывании n вверх в данном случае.
Но в целом это реализуется так:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Turtle.Speed = 10;
        int n =-45; //создаем переменную
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            for (int j = n + 15; j == 90; j++) //
            {
                Draw(150, ref n); //прокидываем в метод ссылку на нее (ключевое слово ref)
            }
        }
    }

static void Draw(int len, ref int n) //в методе меняем переменную, она уйдет назад.
{
    int[] array = new int [2];

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        Turtle.Move(len / 2);
        Turtle.Turn(array[i] = n);
    }

    Turtle.Turn(180 - n);

    for (int i = 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        Turtle.Move(len / 2);
        Turtle.Turn(-array[i]);
    }

    Turtle.Turn(-180 + n);
}
```

Comment: А зачем `ref`? `n` же внутри метода не меняется?

Comment: Видимо вы правы, я не правильно задал свой вопрос. В общем если убрать циклы, то моя черепашка рисует линию 50, потом поворачивает на -45 градусов и рисует еще линию 50, после она возвращается в начальную точку. Вот мне надо сделать чтобы следующий ее ход был, рисовать линию 50, поворачивать -45 + новый угол 15 и рисовать линию 50, возвращаться на исходную точку и так делать 7 раз.

Comment: А зачем ref? n же внутри метода не меняется?  - ну тут я ответил на вопрос "как получить доступ к переменной", вдруг потом будет меняться.

Comment: А по поводу сдвига, в методы можно передавать переменную. Собственно переменная n уже есть. Достаточно во внешнем цикле менять её значение и строить линию по новому углу. Для этих целей мой код подойдет, достаточно только ref убрать (он тут не нужен действительно).